# Optimistic locking not working with spring data couchbase @version

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

As mentioned in spring data couchbase reference guide, i am trying to enable optimistic locking feature using @Version annotation. My expectation is couchbase will populate version field when a doucument is mutated. But seems like it is not populating the version field. its always 0. Following is my Pojo, and using crudRepository to save the document. when i update i try to send version as 1 to simulate optimitic locking exception. But i didn't get any exception the update went fine. Since the documentation is not helping much, i could not proceed further. Any help will be greatly appreciated?

```
@Document
public class Project extends BusinessEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1665165729053936288L;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private String description;

    @Version
    private long version;


    public Project() {

    }

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Project(String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the version
     */
    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * @param version the version to set
     */
    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its my fault. Couchbase populates version field.But we are requried to send version number while saving.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? I am having the same issue but don't quite understand how you fixed it.

Comment: Yes same here, can you please share us this answer via coding.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this could fail is that you need to have a getter for your `@version` field.